# How to add icons to the filesymbols?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, nautilus, icons

I am facing the issue of not having any icons associated with my file-types. Like for a directory containing a LaTeX document, only the pdf and the synctex.gz have icons, but I'd like to also see especially in the tex-file the icon of the default application with which this file-type is associated with. For example the texmaker or texstudio icon.

This does not only concern tex-files, but also Javascript, Matlab, etc

How can this be achieved?

Thanks!

> [image: pic that shows nautilus window with files]